# ValueError when trying to split DataFrame into train/test

Tags: python, keras

I am getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` from this code:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = data
print(x_train.shape)  
print(y_train.shape)  
print(y_train[:3])
```

I checked similar questions in this error but couldn't solve it.

[image]

Comment: I think You should use `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)` to split the data, you can't assign `dataframe` directly to `tuples`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to unpack the `data` variable into two separate pieces, each of which should contain another two outputs (an `x` and `y`) variable. However, `data` is simply a single output, which is a pandas dataframe for which unpacking doesn't work. Based on the code you provided it seems you are trying to split your data into a training and test dataset. This does not work this way if you have the data stored as a single dataframe. You will have to split the manually yourself into a feature array and an array of values you are trying to predict, which you can then split into a training and test dataset using the [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function from `scikit-learn`.